# MySql ENUM sorting with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have the following model:

There are clients (`Clients` table), each one have one address or more (`Addresses` table).
Each address **might** have one phone number, either landline or mobile (`PhoneNumbers` table`):
[image]

Unfortunately I cannot change the DB design, it was given to me with the project.

The task I need to perform is to list all clients with their addresses, and for each address the corresponding phone number if exists.

The problem is that **I need to sort the results according to phone-number type:**

- First I need to list addresses with **landline** numbers
- after it I need to list addresses with **mobile** number
- lastly I need to list addresses **without any number**

I got with the following query:

```
SELECT Clients.last_name, Clients.first_name, Addresses.city, PhoneNumbers.line_type, 
PhoneNumbers.line_number
FROM Clients 
INNER JOIN Addresses ON Addresses.client_id = Clients.id
LEFT JOIN PhoneNumbers ON PhoneNumbers.address_id = Addresses.id
ORDER BY Clients.last_name, Clients.first_name, FIELD(PhoneNumbers.line_type, 'landline','mobile');
```

The problem is that addresses without any number are listed first:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| last_name | first_name | city      | line_type | line_number |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Gracia    | Maria      | Madrid    | NULL      | NULL        |
| Gracia    | Maria      | Madrid    | landline  | 911111111   |
| Gracia    | Maria      | Madrid    | mobile    | 666111111   |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Any idea how can I make these entries being listed at the end for each client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIELD(NULL, {values list})` always returns NULL.

NULL is the most least value in ORDER BY always.

Use `ORDER BY ..., PhoneNumbers.line_type IS NULL, PhoneNumbers.line_type = 'mobile'`.

`PhoneNumbers.line_type IS NULL` puts the rows with NULL last.

`PhoneNumbers.line_type = 'mobile'` puts the rows with value of `'mobile'` after another values (but before NULL values which were moved last on previous sorting step).

Answer (score 0):

I find that this would be simpler done with a `case` expression:

```
order by client.last_name, client_first_name,
    case phonenumbers.line_type
        when 'landline' then 1
        when 'mobile'   then 2
        else 3
    end
```

Alternatively, you can use the `null`-safe operator:

```
order by client.last_name, client_first_name,
    phonenumbers.line_type <=> 'landline' desc,
    phonenumbers.line_type <=> 'mobile' desc
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIND_IN_SET** is your friend:-) you can use as follow

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(if(line_type IS NULL,"",line_type),"landline,mobile,");
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set @v:=NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select FIND_IN_SET(if(@v IS NULL,"",@v),"landline,mobile,");
+------------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET(if(@v IS NULL,"",@v),"landline,mobile,") |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    3 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> set @v:="landline";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select FIND_IN_SET(if(@v IS NULL,"",@v),"landline,mobile,");
+------------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET(if(@v IS NULL,"",@v),"landline,mobile,") |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    1 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> set @v:="mobile";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select FIND_IN_SET(if(@v IS NULL,"",@v),"landline,mobile,");
+------------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET(if(@v IS NULL,"",@v),"landline,mobile,") |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    2 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

change @v to your field and put FIND_IN_SET in your ORDER BY